# How to customize pagination and arrow in swiper js using react ( next js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I try to find the documentation for customizing pagiantion ( dots ) and arrow for react/next js  but i couldnt find that

I want to customize the dots and arrow from the swiper js and make my own component not replacing the css